# map with tidy eval with paste

Tags: r, tidyeval

I need to run lm on nested data and use `map` with `lm`. But I put it in a function to have a different set of independent variables in the model. The code looks like this

predictors1<-c("TWO_YEAR_PRIOR_SCALE_0","PV1.Dim1")

```
student_progress_model<-function(df, predictors){
  lm(
  as.formula(paste("SCALE_SCORE_0", paste(predictors, collapse="+"), sep="~")),
  data=df, na.action=na.exclude)
}
    
data_nested<-data_nested%>%      
  mutate(
    model=map(data, student_progress_model(df=., predictors=predictors1)),
    stand_resids = map2(data, model, rstandard)
  )
```

It comes up with the error that `object 'SCALE_SCORE_0' not found`

How can i specify that my variables are in the data passed to the function? Is it something to do with tidy eval?
I tried to put {{}} in my function like

```
lm(
      as.formula(paste("SCALE_SCORE_0", paste({{predictors}}, collapse="+"), sep="~")),
      data=df, na.action=na.exclude)
```

But it does not help...

also, will `rstandard` give me standardised residuals this way?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: The problem might be that you're supplying an expression to `map()` instead of a function or lambda.